# Byte Buddy can't load my Interceptor class because it depends on classes from another ClassLoader

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have Byte Buddy library in one ClassLoader and I'm trying to hot swap a class from a neighbor ClassLoader where Byte Buddy is unavailable, but many other unique classes are present. I created an interceptor annotated with Byte Buddy annotations and using these unique classes and configured my java project to have both dependencies on compile path and it compiles.

However, when I try to instantiate a Byte Buddy Advice using this interceptor it naturally fails with `NoClassDefFoundError` because the class object I'm passing belongs to either BB's classloader or the neighbor classloader and either the BB annotations or the unique classes aren't there.

How to circumvent this? Will `MultipleParentClassLoader` help? Is it possible to create an unannotated interceptor?

```
public class OverrideWriteAccessInterceptor {
    private OverrideWriteAccessInterceptor() {
        //
    }

    // @Advice. is a  BB class
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void inlinedEnterOverrideWriteAccess(
            // ObjectMember is a unique class
            @Advice.This final ObjectMember _this) {
        ...
    }
}
...
Method mtdOverrideWriteAccess = ...;
Class<?> interceptorClass = OverrideWriteAccessInterceptor.class;

final ForDeclaredMethods visitorWrapper =
    new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods()
        .method(
            ElementMatchers.anyOf(mtdOverrideWriteAccess),
            Advice.to(interceptorClass)); // NoClassDefFoundError ObjectMember at getDeclaredMethods

final Class<?> declaringClass = mtdOverrideWriteAccess.getDeclaringClass();

new ByteBuddy()
    .redefine(declaringClass)
    .visit(visitorWrapper)
    .make()
    .load(declaringClass.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
```